# How to init a reference to a class that is declared in a separate file?

Tags: c++, singleton, cppunit

```
class Foo{
    void operator=(const Foo&){};   
public:
    Foo(){};
};

Foo& fooRef(){
    static Foo aFoo;
    return aFoo;
}
int main() {
    Foo &foo = fooRef();
    return 0;
}
```

This code works properly without issuing any errors. As soon as I change the body of the main to:

```
int main(){
    Foo &foo; 
    foo = fooRef();
    return 0;
}
```

the compiler tries to use the `operator=` and hence complains. So my first question is: why does it make a difference?

The way I arrived to this fact is that I am doing unit testing using `CPPunit` where I have to test a singleton class that has the signature of `getInstance()` being `Singleton& getInstance()`. To do my testing I am trying to init an instance in singleton in the `TestSingleton` class. Hence having:

```
class TestSingleton{
...
private:
    Singleton &instance;
};


void TestSingleton::setUp(){
    this->instance = Singleton::getInstance();
}
```

Which having the above example issues an error (as the `operator=` is declared private, and if it would not be, it is obvious I do not wont it to be invoked). So the second question is: how would I avoid this and get an instance of singleton in my `TestSingleton` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

References cannot be neither default initialized nor re-seated. They have to refer to an existing object from the beginning. They are just aliases for another object.

> So the second question is: how would I avoid this and get an instance of singleton in my `TestSingleton` class?

You can initialize reference members using the constructor initialization list:

```
class TestSingleton{
...
  TestSingleton(Singleton& s) : instance(s) {}
private:
    Singleton &instance;
};
```

If you find that you need to be able to default initialize and then re-seat a "reference", you should use a pointer or an optional type instead (see `boost::optional` for example). But in this particular case, since you are dealing with a singleton, there is actually no need to store a reference to it. You can simply use `Singleton::getInstance()` whenever you need it.

Comment: I am not sure that the Constructor is an option for `CPPunit`. From what I know the only method that is called before the test, is `setUp` and you usually do not invoke any class constructors.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie Then you may need to use a pointer to singleton instead. On the other hand, it is a singleton. Why not just get an instance whenever you need it?

Comment: Well, this is the point of the question, the way the `getInstance()` method is designed I have only a reference to the object...

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie `instance = &Singleton::getInstance();`. But, as I said, you can just use `Singleton::getInstance()` whenever you need it. You don't need to cache a pointer or reference to is. That is one of the "virtues" of the singleton anti-pattern.